# Using jQuery .nextUntil() on split lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to get the .nextUntil() to work on split lists, or get the same functionality?

---

So I am trying to implement the ever so popular shift select for my items, and since they are ordered in a list in my application I want to be able to select across `<ul>` borders.

I have the following set of DOM elements:

```html
<ul class="current">
  <li class="item">first</li>
  <li class="item clicked">second</li>
  <li class="item">third</li>
  <li class="item">fourth</li>
</ul>
<ul class="later">
  <li class="item">fifth</li>
  <li class="item selected">sixth</li>
  <li class="item">seventh</li>
</ul>
```

And using something like this:

```js
$('li.clicked').nextUntil('li.selected');
```

I'd like a list containing the following elements

```html
[ <li class="item">third</li>,
  <li class="item">fourth</li>,
  <li class="item">fifth</li> ]
```

However all I get is the elements leading up to the split `</ul>`. Is there any way of doing this? I have also tried to first selecting all items with `$('.item')`and then using `.nextUntil()` on them without any luck.

Comment: will "clicked" always be in the `current` ul? and `selected` in the "later" ul?

Comment: No, I guess not. The user can select the items in any order, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
$('li').slice($('li').index($('.clicked'))+1,$('li').index($('.selected')));
```

For reference

[Jquery.Index](https://api.jquery.com/index/)

[Jquery.Slice](https://api.jquery.com/slice/)

**Edit**

So if you do

```
$('li')
```

you will get an array of all elements 'li' getting:

```
[<li class=​"item">​first​</li>​, 
<li class=​"item clicked">​second​</li>​, 
<li class=​"item">​third​</li>​, 
<li class=​"item">​fourth​</li>​, 
<li class=​"item">​fifth​</li>​, 
<li class=​"item selected">​sixth​</li>​, 
<li class=​"item">​seventh​</li>​]
```

Since it is an array you can slice him to get an sub array you just need two positions, where to start and here to finish.

```
//start
$('li').index($('.clicked'))+1 // +1 because you dont want to select him self
//end
$('li').index($('.selected'))
```

For better preformance you should before create an array with all li so it will not search all dom 3 times for the array of 'li'

```
var array = $('li');
var subarray = array.slice(array.index($('.clicked'))+1,array.index($('.selected')));
```

Comment: Wow, this works! Now I just need to understand it. :)

Comment: Wonderful, I'll take it!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming these lists cannot be merged into one, it is impossible using the `nextUntil` method. This is because of how jQuery performs traversing. According to the documentation,

> Get all following **siblings** of each element up to but not including the element matched by the selector, DOM node, or jQuery object passed.

`fifth` is not a sibling of the `clicked` element, but rather it is a child of the sibling of the element's parents.

I came up with two possible solutions.

**Solution 1: Combine NEXT and PREV traversals**

Assuming that `.clicked` is always in the first list and `.selected` is always in the second list, combining `prevAll()` with `nextAll()` should do the trick. This assumes that the order is the same.

```
var siblings = $("li.clicked").nextAll()
```

Get all siblings of the current element AFTER the element itself.

```
var distantSiblings = $("li.selected").prevAll();
```

Get all distant siblings after the first element, but before the second one.

```
siblings.push(distantSiblings);
```

Combine them into two and then iterate over each element.

```js
var siblings = $("li.clicked").nextAll()
var distantSiblings = $("li.selected").prevAll();

siblings.push(distantSiblings);

siblings.each(function() {
    $(this).addClass("blue");
});
```

```css
.blue { color: blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="current">
  <li class="item">first</li>
  <li class="item clicked">second</li>
  <li class="item">third</li>
  <li class="item">fourth</li>
</ul>
<ul class="later">
  <li class="item">fifth</li>
  <li class="item selected">sixth</li>
  <li class="item">seventh</li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r15z10o4/

**Note:**

You will notice that the above code works, however it might not be the optimal solution. This is only confirmed to work for your example above. There may also be a less verbose solution.

**Solution 2 (Find index of all list items)**

Another idea is to find the index of all items, and collect the elements that are sandwiched between those two indices. You will then want to use the 'slice' selector to get the range in between.

```
var items = $(".item");
var clicked = $(".clicked");
var selected = $(".selected");
var clickIndex = items.index(clicked);
var selectIndex = items.index(selected);

$("li").slice(clickIndex + 1, selectIndex).addClass("blue");
```

```js
var clicked = $(".clicked");
var selected = $(".selected");

var clickIndex = $("li").index(clicked);
var selectIndex = $("li").index(selected);

$("li").slice(clickIndex+1, selectIndex).addClass("blue");
```

```css
.blue { color: blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="current">
  <li class="item">first</li>
  <li class="item clicked">second</li>
  <li class="item">third</li>
  <li class="item">fourth</li>
</ul>
<ul class="later">
  <li class="item">fifth</li>
  <li class="item selected">sixth</li>
  <li class="item">seventh</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: +1 for clarifying the `.nextUntil()` function. I ended up with a solution that looks a lot like your second alternative. But I saw it first in the other answer. 
Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it manually by selecting all these items at once, and using loops.

Consider the parent element, let's say "container":

```
<div id="container">
  <ul class="current">
    <li class="item">first</li>
    <li class="item clicked">second</li>
    <li class="item">third</li>
    <li class="item">fourth</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="later">
    <li class="item">fifth</li>
    <li class="item selected">sixth</li>
    <li class="item">seventh</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Now, you can select all these items:

```
var $items = $("#container > ul > li.item"); // or simply $("#container .item");
```

And iterate through them:

```
var $items = $(".item"), $result = $(), found = false;

for (var i = 0; i < $items.length; i++)
{
    $currentItem = $items.eq(i);

    if ($currentItem.is('.clicked')) {
        found = true;
        continue;
    }

    if ($currentItem.is('.selected'))
        break;

    if (found)
      $result = $result.add($currentItem);
}

console.log($result);
```

Here is the working [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ykurmangaliyev/8Lyro9tc/).

Answer (score 0):

In any case it feels like you will need to define groups of li.

I think the easiest is to create a function getting a list of lis that you can request any way you want then to filter the el you are interested in.

```js
function elRange(elList, start, end){
  // we do not use indexOf directly as elList is likely to be a node list
  // and not an array.
  var startI = [].indexOf.call(elList, start);
  var endI = [].indexOf.call(elList, end);
  return [].slice.call(elList, startI, endI + 1);
}

// request the group of *ordered* elements that can be selected
var liList = document.querySelectorAll('ul.current > li, ul.later > li');
var selectionEnd = document.querySelector('.selected');

[].forEach.call(liList, function(li){
  li.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var selected = elRange(liList, li, selectionEnd);
    selected.forEach(function(el){
      el.classList.add('red');
    })
  });
});
```

```css
.selected {
  color: blue;
}
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="current">
  <li class="item">first</li>
  <li class="item">second</li>
  <li class="item">third</li>
  <li class="item">fourth</li>
</ul>
<ul class="later">
  <li class="item">fifth</li>
  <li class="item selected">sixth</li>
  <li class="item">seventh</li>
</ul>
```